# Execute method from other class JavaFX

Tags: javafx, methods

I have a little problem.I have an Stage with a table view . Im counting the rows with this method:

```
public void count() {
    int number;
    number= tableview.getItems().size();
    lblcount.setText(String.valueOf(number));

}
```

I have a second stage with the same tableview ,but in this stage i can delete rows. I need to  refresh the first tableview or the count, in each change what im doing in the second tableview.

BUt if i call the method from the second stage nothing happens.

Im doing this in the second Stage:

Class1 C1 = new Class1();
    C1.count();

I need to execute the method in the first Stage and update or refresh the count of the tableview from the other Stage.

Thanks in advance.. :D

Comment: I am guessing your `Class` is your first `Controller`. You can't do `ControllerName C1 = new ControllerName(); ControllerName.count();`, you can pass the data to your new `Controller`.,<- If you are using `FXML` You also say that you are using the same `TableView` in two different `Stages`. This should be impossible unless you remove the `TableView` from the first `Stage` and add it to the second `Stage`. <- If you are using pure code. If you have a `TableView` in your second stage, simple call `thatTableViewName.getItems.size()`

Comment: Yes, it is probably an incorrect dependency injection.